# java.io.NotSerializableException in Weblogic cluster

Tags: spring, jsf, serialization, weblogic, cluster-computing

We have a Weblogic cluster with a couple of nodes, where we have deployed a web application based in JSF, Richfaces, Hibernate and Spring.

The application seems to run fine, but we are having the following error in the log, every 2-3 seconds:

```
<Jun 25, 2015 6:08:14 PM CEST> <Error> <Cluster> <BEA-000126> <All session objects should be serializable to replicate. Check the objects in the session. Failed to replicate a non-serializable object.
java.rmi.MarshalException: failed to marshal update(Lweblogic.cluster.replication.ROID;ILjava.io.Serializable;Ljava.lang.Object;); nested exception is:
    java.io.NotSerializableException: <Some @Service class name here>
    at weblogic.rjvm.BasicOutboundRequest.marshalArgs(BasicOutboundRequest.java:92)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicRemoteRef.invoke(BasicRemoteRef.java:300)
    at weblogic.cluster.replication.ReplicationManager_12120_WLStub.update(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor773.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

We don't have a cluster in local to test, so I added an snippet of code to serialize the object from one of the controllers and see if serialization went ok in a local environment:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream outputObj;
try {
    outputObj = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
    outputObj.writeObject(service);
    outputObj.close();
    outputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`service` is here an instance of the service class shown in the stacktrace, annotated with `@Autowired`.

The approach I followed to solve this has been setting a breakpoint for NotSerializableException and implementing `java.io.Serializable` and adding a generated serial version UID in all the classes complaining in debug. As there were a lot of them I finally did this to all the Services (annotated with `@Service`) and all repository classes (`@Repository`). Those classes are not complaining anymore, but now I have `JaxWsClientProxy` complaining about the same.

I cannot touch this class as it is external to my application. Besides, I didn't find any reference to it in my code so I can set it to transient. Even if I found any references, I am not sure whether it is safe to do so.

The application runs well so I have been suggested that this exception could be ignored. On the other hand, I would like to know whether the service/repository classes should be replicated on WS clusters and what is the correct way to do so.

**EDIT:** As per @sunrise76 comment:

> can you check below link?
>   cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/session-management-td549278.html. I think
>   your session should not be type of the class in that jar –  sunrise76

I am not sure how to use the info you passed to me, so I instead checked who was instantiating this `JaxWsClientProxy` class. It turned out to be Spring when instantiating a bean called `clientPEndpoint` and another called `clientGEndpoint`.

I checked the project and found this on an XML where we have the Apache Camel configuration:

```
<jaxws:client id="clientPEndpoint"
        address="${ws.endPoint}" 
        serviceClass="<some service class>"
        endpointName="s:Connector" serviceName="s:ConnectorPortType"
        xmlns:s="<some namespace>">
        <jaxws:outInterceptors>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <map>
                        <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
                        <entry key="user" value="${ws.user}" />
                        <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />
                        <entry key="passwordCallbackRef">
                            <ref bean="myPasswordCallback" />
                        </entry>
                    </map>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" id="logOut" parent="abstractLoggingInterceptor"  />
        </jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <jaxws:inInterceptors> 
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" id="logIn" parent="abstractLoggingInterceptor" /> 
        </jaxws:inInterceptors> 
        <jaxws:dataBinding>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding">
                <property name="extraClass">
                    <list>
                        <value><some ObjectFactory class></value>
                        ..........
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
       </jaxws:dataBinding>
    </jaxws:client>

    <jaxws:client id="clientGEndpoint"
        address="${g.ws.endPoint}"      
        serviceClass="<some service class>"
        endpointName="s:WebServiceService" serviceName="s:WebService"
        xmlns:s="<some namespace>">
        <jaxws:outInterceptors>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <map>
                    <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
                        <entry key="user" value="${g.ws.user}" />
                        <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />
                        <entry key="passwordCallbackRef">
                            <ref bean="gPasswordCallback" />
                        </entry>
                    </map>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
             <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" id="logOut" parent="abstractLoggingInterceptor"  />
        </jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <jaxws:inInterceptors> 
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" id="logIn" parent="abstractLoggingInterceptor" /> 
        </jaxws:inInterceptors> 
        <jaxws:dataBinding>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding">
                <property name="extraClass">
                    <list>
                        <value><some ObjectFactory class></value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
       </jaxws:dataBinding>
    </jaxws:client>
```

I would say that this configuration is making Spring create instances of `JaxWsClientProxy`, but I am not completely sure.

Anyway, as M.Deinum said, I am not sure I should be serializing instances of services/DAOs, so maybe I should be aiming to some Weblogic configuration.

Comment: But Serializaiton exception will print the exact class which is not Serializable. Are you getting error even after addressing all these exceptions?

Comment: Why are the services even serialized, you shouldn't be serializing application scoped beans imho.

Comment: @sunrise76: I addressed all the classes inside my application, but I came upon this `JaxWsClientProxy` which I cannot manipulate because it's into a library. Besides, I don't find any reference to it in my code so I am not sure how it is related to the other classes (I guessed Spring-related). @M. Deinum: I agree with you. I am not sure about the reason  but I think all those classes shouldn't be serializable. I am just trying to figure out why WS tries to serialize them anyway and how to solve it. Not sure if I have to configure something in the Weblogic Server or so....

Answer (score -2):

You should check out the Class object(service) that be Serializable and variables inside it have ability serializable for example int can be and ImageView cannot be.you should add transient before this variable.
NotSerializableException it is throw when you want to serialize an object, which has not been marked as Serializable.you should implements all class with serializable.

Comment: No, you should implement the classes that *need* to be Serializable with Serializable.

Comment: @sajad: Thanks for your feedback. As I already stated in the question, I made serializable all the classes I had within reach. The problem came when I came to `JaxWsClientProxy` which I cannot manipulate. I even haven't found any reference to it in my code, so I don't know where it comes from and therefore I cannot make it transient (even not sure whether is safe to do so).

Comment: is org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy  required for your project? If not, remove this dependency and check the code.

Comment: @sunrise76: Unfortunately it is a dependency of an artifact called `camel-cxf` which is required for the project. I don't think I can just get rid of it. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: can you check below link? http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/session-management-td549278.html. I think your session should not be type of the class in that jar